# Indirect binding of variables to values through an if condition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Define a function $f$ by,

$$f(x, y) = \text{if } x = y \text{ then } x \text{ else } f(x-1, y) $$

Then what are the possible values for $z$ in,

$$ \exists a: a\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge z  = \frac{a}{f(5, a)} $$

This isn't exactly difficult. Just weird. It is designed to mess with your thinking in a few ways. I'll be interested to see what you think.

Comment: $$\text{If } a\leq y\land a\ne 0\land a\in\mathbb{Z};\;\dfrac{a}{f(5,a)}=1$$

Comment: Why the $a \le y$? The $ a \ne 0 $ avoids the divide by zero. But does this invalid division invalidate the whole expression? The question is more about how you reason about it. 1 is the answer but why? And how do you reason about the infinite recursion?

Comment: It's $a\leq 5$ the limitation. I wrote it wrong. Because if $a=6$ then the iteration never ends. Indeed $x$ decreases each step and will never be $6$ or more.  The actual solution is $$\text{If } a\leq 5\land a\ne 0\land a\in\mathbb{Z};\;\dfrac{a}{f(5,a)}=1$$

Comment: @ Raffaele I think you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the value of $a$ in,

$$ \exists a: a\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge z  = \frac{a}{f(5, a)} $$

But there does exist some value. I think of this as,
$$ a = 0 \wedge a\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge z  = \frac{a}{f(5, a)} $$
or
$$ a = 1 \wedge a\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge z  = \frac{a}{f(5, a)} $$
or
... for all the real numbers.

This is an uncountably infinite number of lines of math. Hard to iterate through.

So let's leave it unbound, in our thinking. It has a value and we will decide what it is later.

But we first come across it in the numerator, and we don't know the value yet. Let's look at $f(5, a)$. $f$ is defined recursively and we could rearrange it. But the peculiar structure doesn't help us.

$$f(5, a) = \text{if } 5 = a \text{ then } x \text{ else } f(4, a) $$

The $5=a$ doesn't give us any constraint on $a$. The condition could be true or false. We need consider both cases. If it is true, 
$$a=5 \wedge f(5, a) = 5 \wedge z = 1$$
So that is one solution. If false, then $f(5, a) = f(4, a)$.
$$a=4 \wedge f(4, a) = 4 \wedge z = 1$$
... all the way down till we get to, $ f(5, a) = f(0, a) $
$$a=0 \wedge f(0, a) = 0 \wedge z = \frac{0}{0}$$

But dividing by zero is illegal. The result is undefined.

And there is still the possibility that a is not equal to 0. Which heads off to infinity , but always giving the same value $z = 1$.

So what does it mean to have a zero divide by zero in here. $a = 5$ gives a perfectly good value for z. If we only wanted one solution, we might have stopped there. Does the existence of the zero divide by zero, invalidate that value?

The question is designed to test the strange way that the if condition binds a parameter to a function to a value, as one possibility. For me this question raises questions about how we reason about math.